# Writing excel formula into file using python and enumerate

Tags: python, excel

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('myfile')
for i, CellObj in enumerate(ws['A'], 1):
        CellObj.value = '=IF(A2=A1,"N","Y")'.format
wb.save('myfile.xlsx')
```

Above is my formula in python. The goal is that if A2 = A1, then it will produce Y, else N in column J.

But I am getting syntax error in second last line.

Comment: What does the 'i' do?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. If you're getting a syntax error, what does this have to do with Excel?

Comment: @amc hi sorry, lets just say I don't know how to write code (im new!)

If I want python to read each cell in A and compare to previous cell to see if value has changed, how can write the code such that column J will output "Yes" or "No"

Comment: To explain better....

Say A1 contains 123 and A2 contains 132 and A3 contains 132. In cell J1, Python will type Y. J2, it will type Y and J3 it will type N, because A3 matches A2

Comment: @plshelpimpoor That’s a different question entirely, and one which might be off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, your explanation is confusing me, but I managed to put together some code for you to play with.

I understand that you compare A2 to A1, A3 to A2 and so forth. But I don't understand what you compare A1 to?

```
import openpyxl

file_name = r'workbook.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
sheet_name = 'myfile'
sheet = wb[sheet_name]

# loops the row numbers starting from row 2 until the last row number (1-based)
# which contains data.
for row_num in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
    # cid means cell id like A1, A2, J1, ect.
    current_cid = "{}{}".format("A", row_num)
    compare_cid = "{}{}".format("A", row_num-1)
    target_cid = "{}{}".format("J", row_num)
    sheet[target_cid]='=IF({}={}, "N", "Y")'.format(current_cid, compare_cid)

wb.save(file_name)
```

Comment: Hello kind sir. Thank you for putting the code. Sorry english isn't my first language...

A1 is the column header so I am sorry. We will start with A2 being compared to A1.

Comment: OK, got it. Then you should be fine.